# counter does not stop after it reaches the limit

Tags: java

i am making a tally counter for my class, we have to set a limit for when the counter reaches a certain amount but when it does it keeps on going instead of stopping.
my teacher also wants us to use things like "Math.max(n,0)" but i don't see why we would use that over an if statement.

```
int i=1;
boolean ticking = true;
running:
while (ticking){

String tally = input.nextLine();           

if (tally.equalsIgnoreCase("z"))
{
    System.out.println(i++);
    continue running;
}
else if (tally.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
{
    System.out.println(i--);
    continue running;
}
else if (i<=0 || i>=10)
{
    System.out.println("Cant go no more");
    continue running;
}
```

Comment: you never change the value of `ticking` and why are you using `continue running;`?

Comment: Counting will stop when you set the `ticking` variable to false inside any of your `if` statements.

Comment: Ask yourself: is the if statement with `i <= 0 || i >= 10` ever reached when you press `z` or `x`? And what would happen if you were to `continue` at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify a loop exit condition.
`ticking` is indeed never set to `false` during the loop.

Here, you should probably allow the loop to exit but you go on :

```
else if (i<=0 || i>=10)
{
    System.out.println("Cant go no more");
    continue running;
}
```

By setting `ticking` to `false` you exit the loop.
Besides, you should use a `if` statement rather than an `else-if` statement if you want to prevent to loop again if this condition `i<=0 || i>=10` is `true` right now after having incremented or decremented `i`.

It would give :

```
if (tally.equalsIgnoreCase("z"))
{
    System.out.println(i++);
    continue running;
}
else if (tally.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
{
    System.out.println(i--);
    continue running;
}

if (i<=0 || i>=10)
{
    System.out.println("Cant go no more");
    ticking = false;
}
```

As side notes,  why do you use a labeled loop ? 
Using it makes sense as you have nested loops and that you want to continue or break the outer loop.

And also why do you add a `continue` statement at the end of each conditional statement ?
The `if-else-if` statements don't execute the next conditional statement as one of these is `true`.

---

> my teacher also wants us to use things like "Math.max(n,0)" but i
>   don't see why we would use that over an if statement.

I am not sure to get it.
What is exactly the requirement ?

Anyway, `Math.max(n,0)` will not replace `i<=0 || i>=10` as this last condition checks that the value is both between min and max range while `Math.max(n,0)` will only help you to check that the value is not superior to max.

Comment: i attempted to change ticking to false but it keeps on ticking. also i put the continue statement because otherwise my code stops running after 1 tick.

Comment: @Paladin-San I think that I understood the problem. Check my edit.

Comment: thanks that helped a lot, i fixed it by removing the continue statements. looks like i didn't need them after all.

Answer (score 1):

Once you reach your limit you'll want to set ticking to false.

```
if (i<=0 || i>=10)
{
    ticking = false;
    System.out.println("Cant go no more");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1- statements inside your last condition ie `else if (i<=0 || i>=10)` block will execute only when value of `tally` is not equal to `"z"` or `"x"`

2- to stop counting you need to set ticking equal to false:

```
else if (i<=0 || i>=10) {
    ticking = false;
    System.out.println("Cant go no more"); 
}
```

and for Math.max(n,0) i think this is expected to print the count
like

`System.out.println("Total Count: "+Math.max(i,0));`

---

you need something like this:

```
        int i=1;
        boolean ticking = true;
        running:
            while (ticking){

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String tally = sc.nextLine();           

            if (tally.equalsIgnoreCase("z"))
            {
                System.out.println(i++);
            }
            else if (tally.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
            {
                System.out.println(i--);
            }
            if (i<=0 || i>=10)
            {
                ticking = false;
                System.out.println("Cant go no more");
            }
            continue running;

        }
    System.out.println("Total Count: "+Math.max(i,0));
```